# Написать linq аналог алгоритма

Tags: c#, linq

```
double min = Math.Abs(mass.Average() - mass[0]);
int ind = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < mass.Length; i++)
    if (Math.Abs(mass.Average() - mass[i]) < min)
    {
        min = Math.Abs(mass.Average() - mass[i]);
        ind = i;
    }
```

Необходимо найти индекс элемента, максимально приближенного к среднему арифметическому и записать в linq форме

Comment: Код в вопрос текстом.

Comment: И ты в курсе, что приведённый код квадратичный вместо линейного?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

допустим, есть массив

```
var mass = new [] {1, 3, 8, 11};
```

Тода однострочный медленный вариант

```
Console.WriteLine(mass.Select((m, i)=>(i,m))
                    .OrderBy(m=>Math.Abs(m.m - mass.Average())).First().i);
```

Двухстрочный, но чуть более быстрый

```
var average = mass.Average();
Console.WriteLine(mass.Select(( m, i)=>( Math.Abs(m-average) ,i))
                      .OrderBy(m=>m.Item1).First().i);
```

Самый быстрый - без linq, простым циклом пробежаться.

```
int ind = 0;
var average = mass.Average();
for(int i=1; i<mass.Length; i++)
{
    if (Math.Abs(mass[i] - average) < Math.Abs(mass[ind] - average))
    ind = i;
}

Console.WriteLine(ind);
```

Comment: Не могли бы вы объяснить, за что отвечают m и i? Select((m, i)=>(i,m))

Comment: m - значение из массива, i - индекс элемента в массиве

Comment: Объясните еще пожалуйста, как именно здесь работает OrderBy. Не совсем понимаю, как он может сортировать по элементу, которого в массиве может и не быть.

Comment: Вам надо найти элемент в массиве, максимально близкий к среднему. То есть разница между средним и искомым элементом должна быть минимальна. Таким образом, если мы построим массив разниц между средним и элементами из массива, потом эти разницы отсортируем по возрастанию, то в начале будет минимальная разница, которую мы ищем.

Comment: Разобрался, большое спасибо за помощь

Comment: @Gendalf на здоровье